# What is the equivalent of C++ '*&' in C ?. Does it even exist?

Tags: c++, c

for example, how to implement this C++ code in C ?

```
void someFunction(type *&outParamOnly) ;
returnType someOtherFunction() ;
...
returnType someOtherFunction()
{
    type *data = NULL ;
    someFunction(data) ;
    ...
}
...
void someFunction(type *&outParamOnly)
{
    bool condition ;
    int array_len ;
    ...
    if(condition) // variable's value passed to this function stays as it was
    return ;
    ...
    outParamOnly = new type[array_len] ; // value is moddified and it's reflected in 'someOtherFunction'
    ...
}
...
```

I'm asking because I don't know how to create such equivalent. Does it's complex ?. In fact I don't know much about C, but much more about C++ syntax, etc. I'm used to write in C++ and once I tryied C to feel diffrence I'm not doing well when trying to implement what I want. I expect positive answer - that it possible to create some equivalent,
but will it be running faster then in C++ or slower ?
Please answer.

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Comment: `new`/`delete` is not C, use `malloc()`/`free()` instead.

Comment: There's no performance advantage to using C instead of C++.  There may be an advantage to writing C++ in a different style (at a different level of abstraction), but you'll get bigger impact from looking for ways to minimize dynamic allocation.  In any case, `std::unique_ptr` is carefully crafted to be just as fast as raw pointers, so be smart and use the smart pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nearest equivalent is a pointer to a pointer; `**`. C doesn't have references.

There is a slight difference in the call and the function; you must send a pointer to the variable and dereference it when you want to use it:

```
void someFunction(type **outParamOnly)
    ...
    *outParamOnly = whatever;
}

someFunction(&data);
```

This is a fairly typical pattern in C.

Comment: Typical, but not necessarily good. Maybe he just needs to return that value.

Comment: @H2CO3 well, obviously depends on the situation. The alternatives are to return structs, pointers to allocated heap memory, or use globals, and all of those have their own drawbacks.

Comment: That's why I wrote "not **necessarily** good" instead of just "not good". Also, he's already using dynamic memory allocation, and whoever tells me that `*outputArg = new Foo[100]` is clearer and/or more straightforward than `return new Foo[100]` is... well... I don't believe it!

Comment: Sometimes I'm in need to modify outputArg after memory allocation and before returning it. That's why I can't just return new Foo[100]. Some other times I need to return more then one argument so just return isn't the case.

Comment: @user1978386 - A good alternative, in the case of your last comment, would be to design the function to accept a pointer to struct.  This will allow you to modify and pass as many arguments as you need.  Although this is NOT equivalent to the title question, it does solve the problem stated in your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to change the function to accept a pointer-to the thing to be modified. In this case, since the value is a pointer, you'll need to declare the function to accept a double-pointer.

Then, when calling the function, pass the address of the value to be modified.

```
someFunction(&data) ;

...
void someFunction(type **outParamOnly)
{

     *outParamOnly = whatever;
```

Or, you could return the value from the function instead of returning `void`.

Answer (score 2):

C has no reference types, so there's no easy "equivalent" for the syntax you are asking about.

One can use a pointer-to-pointer to emulate that behavior. I'm not sure if that's the appropriate solution, though. Why not just **return** the value instead of messing around with various levels of pointers if it's an output argument anyway?

Answer (score 1):

C doesn't have references, but the equivalent is just 'type **'.

```
void someFunction(type **outParamOnly)
{
    if( NULL != outParamOnly )
        *outParamOnly = new type[array_len] ;
}

returnType someOtherFunction()
{
    type *data = NULL ;
    someFunction(&data) ;
}
```

Note that you need the extra dereference when assigning to what's pointed by outParamOnly and you need to pass a pointer to data when calling someFunction.